# Frame overrides Label TextColor only on Android (xamarin-forms)

Tags: android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

I write the following xaml but i have a problem on android. The Frame control overrides color from Label and I dont know why. When i replace a Frame with a Grid working perfect, but i want the Frame for corner radius.

It's a bug ? Can i fix it ?

```
             <Grid x:Name="Frame_6_10">
                <Frame WidthRequest="30" BackgroundColor="#55b040" IsClippedToBounds="true" CornerRadius="10"/>
                <Label Margin="0,7,0,0" Text="6-10" TextColor="White" FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <ContentView HeightRequest="7" VerticalOptions="Start" WidthRequest="30" BackgroundColor="#55b040"/>
             </Grid>
```

[image]

[image]

I use Xamarin Forms version 3.1.0.697729

Comment: I have a few questions here, like why do you have a frame that has nothing in it? And a label out side it ? And then a content view , what are you trying to do here

Comment: I want only the bottom corners has radius.  I use content view on start for hide the top frame corners.

Comment: You know you should be using images for things like these right? You don't make such layouts with code !!

Comment: Image is not good practise for different resolutions for this scope.

Comment: My question is why all other elements colors where is front of the frame overrided.

Comment: one suggestion.. did you try changing the order of the contentview above the label?

Comment: Change the label frame and contentview to different colors and see what is overriding what!

Comment: For similar UI ,I update xamarin forms to 3.4 and I use BoxView with CornerRadius.Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

well from your code I think it is the content view that covers the label. try to remove it and see what happens .

Comment: The ContentView has excellent position. This not the problem. Thanks

Comment: my apologies , I see that you are right , and this isse is only for android as you explained . cannot you use a boxview instead of a frame ? or have the grid inside the frame

Answer (score 0):

Put your inside your Frame and contentView

```
    <Grid x:Name="Frame_6_10">
         <Frame WidthRequest="30" BackgroundColor="#55b040" IsClippedToBounds="true" 
          CornerRadius="10">
              <ContentView HeightRequest="7" VerticalOptions="Start" 
               WidthRequest="30" BackgroundColor="#55b040">
                    <Label Margin="0,7,0,0" Text="6-10" TextColor="White" 
                       FontSize="16" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                       VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" 
                       FontAttributes="Bold"/>
               </ContentView>
      </Frame>         
</Grid>
```